# Featured content module won't display teasers

Tags: 7, nodes

I am using the featured content block here: http://drupal.org/project/featured_content

I am successful in getting it to display similar items (based on it's search capability) I am electing to display them in teaser form, but the teaser descriptions are not being displayed, only titles. Any insight?

The node tpl.php file being routed through is the same as others which print out the teasers fine through views etc...

Comment: For this type of problem, it's probably best to file a support request on the module's issue queue.  The maintainers know the module better than anyone else and you can follow-up with a full report with them if it turns out to be a bug.